# Force datagridviewcell that host a numeric updown revert it changed on escape key press

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm creating a `datagridviewcell` that host a `numeric updown` control. Everything went fine except one thing. I can't revert changed on escape key press like `textboxcell` or `comboboxcell`. My `datagridviewcell` was created base on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx) example. So anyone have any idea how to revert `numeric updown cell` to previous value on escape key press?

NumericColumn class:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class NumericColumn
    Inherits DataGridViewColumn

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Get, set numeric control min value
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property MinValue() As Decimal
        Get
            Return CType(MyBase.CellTemplate, NumericCell).MinValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            CType(MyBase.CellTemplate, NumericCell).MinValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Get, set numeric control max value
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property MaxValue() As Decimal
        Get
            Return CType(MyBase.CellTemplate, NumericCell).MaxValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            CType(MyBase.CellTemplate, NumericCell).MaxValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Get, set numeric control value
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property NumericControlValue() As Decimal
        Get
            Return CType(MyBase.CellTemplate, NumericCell).NumericControlValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            CType(MyBase.CellTemplate, NumericCell).NumericControlValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicate number of decimal places to display
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property DecimalPlaces() As Integer
        Get
            Return CType(MyBase.CellTemplate, NumericCell).DecimalPlaces
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            CType(MyBase.CellTemplate, NumericCell).DecimalPlaces = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Detemine the value to increment or decrement each time button click
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property Increment() As Integer
        Get
            Return CType(MyBase.CellTemplate, NumericCell).Increment
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            CType(MyBase.CellTemplate, NumericCell).Increment = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(New NumericCell())
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Property CellTemplate() As DataGridViewCell
        Get
            Return MyBase.CellTemplate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DataGridViewCell)

            ' Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell. 
            If (value IsNot Nothing) AndAlso _
                Not value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(GetType(NumericCell)) _
                Then
                Throw New InvalidCastException("Must be a Numeric Cell")
            End If
            MyBase.CellTemplate = value

        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Override clone method to clone new added properties
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Overrides Function Clone() As Object
        Dim obj As NumericColumn = MyBase.Clone()
        obj.MaxValue = Me.MaxValue
        obj.MinValue = Me.MinValue
        obj.NumericControlValue = Me.NumericControlValue
        obj.DecimalPlaces = Me.DecimalPlaces
        obj.Increment = Me.Increment

        Return obj
    End Function
End Class
```

NumericCell class

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class NumericCell
    Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxCell

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Min value for numeric control
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private min As Decimal = 0.0

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Max value for numeric control
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private max As Decimal = 100.0

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Value for numeric control
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private controlValue As Decimal = 0.0

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Decimal places for numeric control
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private places As Integer = 0

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Detemine the value to increment or decrement each time button click
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private incrementStep As Integer = 1

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Get, set numeric control min value
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property MinValue() As Decimal
        Get
            Return Me.min
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            Me.min = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Get, set numeric control max value
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property MaxValue() As Decimal
        Get
            Return Me.max
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            Me.max = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Get, set numeric control value
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property NumericControlValue() As Decimal
        Get
            Return Me.controlValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            Me.controlValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Indicate number of decimal places to display
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property DecimalPlaces() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.places
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Me.places = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Detemine the value to increment or decrement each time button click
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value></value>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Property Increment() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.incrementStep
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Me.incrementStep = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub InitializeEditingControl(ByVal rowIndex As Integer, _
            ByVal initialFormattedValue As Object, _
            ByVal dataGridViewCellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle)

        ' Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value. 
        MyBase.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, _
            dataGridViewCellStyle)

        Dim ctl As NumericEditingControl = CType(DataGridView.EditingControl, NumericEditingControl)
        RemoveHandler ctl.Enter, AddressOf Me.OnNumericEnter
        AddHandler ctl.Enter, AddressOf Me.OnNumericEnter

        'config property for control
        ctl.Minimum = Me.min
        ctl.Maximum = Me.max
        ctl.DecimalPlaces = Me.DecimalPlaces
        ctl.Increment = Me.incrementStep
        ctl.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right
        ctl.ThousandsSeparator = True

        ' Use the default row value when Value property is null. 
        If (Me.Value Is Nothing) Then
            ctl.Value = Me.controlValue
        Else
            ctl.Value = CType(Me.Value, Decimal)
        End If


    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Handle on enter event of numeric
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub OnNumericEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim control As NumericEditingControl = CType(sender, NumericEditingControl)
        Dim strValue As String = control.Value.ToString("N2")
        control.Select(0, strValue.Length)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property EditType() As Type
        Get
            ' Return the type of the editing control that CalendarCell uses. 
            Return GetType(NumericEditingControl)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ValueType() As Type
        Get
            ' Return the type of the value that CalendarCell contains. 
            Return GetType(String)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property DefaultNewRowValue() As Object
        Get
            ' Use the current date and time as the default value. 
            Return 0.0
        End Get
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Override clone method to clone new added properties
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Overrides Function Clone() As Object
        Dim obj As NumericCell = MyBase.Clone()
        obj.MaxValue = Me.MaxValue
        obj.MinValue = Me.MinValue
        obj.NumericControlValue = Me.NumericControlValue
        obj.DecimalPlaces = Me.DecimalPlaces
        obj.Increment = Me.Increment

        Return obj
    End Function
End Class
```

NumericEditingControl class:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class NumericEditingControl
    Inherits NumericUpDown
    Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl

    Private dataGridViewControl As DataGridView
    Private valueIsChanged As Boolean = False
    Private rowIndexNum As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        'Me.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short
    End Sub

    Public Property EditingControlFormattedValue() As Object _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue

        Get
            Return Me.Value.ToString("N2")
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            Try
                ' This will throw an exception of the string is  
                ' null, empty, or not in the format of a date. 
                Me.Value = Decimal.Parse(value)
            Catch
                ' In the case of an exception, just use the default 
                ' value so we're not left with a null value. 
                Me.Value = 0.0
            End Try
        End Set

    End Property

    Public Function GetEditingControlFormattedValue(ByVal context _
        As DataGridViewDataErrorContexts) As Object _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue

        Return Me.Value.ToString("N2")

    End Function

    Public Sub ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(ByVal dataGridViewCellStyle As _
        DataGridViewCellStyle) _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl

        Me.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font
        Me.ForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor
        Me.BackColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor

    End Sub

    Public Property EditingControlRowIndex() As Integer _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex

        Get
            Return rowIndexNum
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            rowIndexNum = value
        End Set

    End Property

    Public Function EditingControlWantsInputKey(ByVal key As Keys, _
        ByVal dataGridViewWantsInputKey As Boolean) As Boolean _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey

        ' Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed. 
        'Select Case key And Keys.KeyCode
        '    Case Keys.Left, Keys.Up, Keys.Down, Keys.Right, _
        '        Keys.Home, Keys.End, Keys.PageDown, Keys.PageUp

        '        Return True

        '    Case Else
        '        Return Not dataGridViewWantsInputKey
        'End Select
        If key.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then

        End If
        Return True

    End Function

    Public Sub PrepareEditingControlForEdit(ByVal selectAll As Boolean) _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit

        ' No preparation needs to be done. 

    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange() _
        As Boolean Implements _
        IDataGridViewEditingControl.RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange

        Get
            Return False
        End Get

    End Property

    Public Property EditingControlDataGridView() As DataGridView _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlDataGridView

        Get
            Return dataGridViewControl
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DataGridView)
            dataGridViewControl = value
        End Set

    End Property

    Public Property EditingControlValueChanged() As Boolean _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlValueChanged

        Get
            Return valueIsChanged
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            valueIsChanged = value
        End Set

    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property EditingControlCursor() As Cursor _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingPanelCursor

        Get
            Return MyBase.Cursor
        End Get

    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnValueChanged(ByVal eventargs As EventArgs)

        ' Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell have changed.
        valueIsChanged = True
        Me.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(True)
        MyBase.OnValueChanged(eventargs)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I am not sure if I have understood what you meant. Are you saying that when you press scape in one of the custom, numericUpDown cells it does not revert to the previous value? After a quick implementation of the example you refer, this is precisely the behaviour I am observing.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it doesn't revert to previous value when I pressed escape

Comment: As said, I am not observing this behaviour in the default configuration (with DateTimePicker) and, after a quick conversion to NumericUpDown, I still don't get a so weird behaviour. Could you please post your code such that I can provider a quicker/more accurate help?

Comment: @varocarbas Code included. Please take a look and show me what I'm doing wrong. I didn't get problem with `DateTimePicker` but `NumericUpdown` got that weird behavior. Even though I handle `NumericUpdown` key_up event in my form and call `DataGridView.CancelEidt()` it still not work

Comment: Thanks. Let me take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part responsible to deal with this behaviour is `EditingControlWantsInputKey`. By looking at the [original code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) it is clear that this part has to be set by default to false (= returning to the previously stored value), but in your code it is set to true. The idea is setting this to true only for ("special") keys which shouldn't provoke the scaping of the value; that is, you don't need to mention here scape, just any other key (triggering this function) which you don't want to provoke the coming-back-to-previous-value behaviour.

Thus, solution:

```
Public Function EditingControlWantsInputKey(ByVal key As Keys, _
    ByVal dataGridViewWantsInputKey As Boolean) As Boolean _
    Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey

    Return False

End Function
```